# EAV how to store additional field value?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-attribute-value

I have a EAV structure in DB and tables: `attribute(id,parent_id,code,name)` and `value(id,entity_id,attribute_id,value)`.

I'm using `parent_id` to store attribute's list. For example,

```
id | parent_id | code | name
1 | null | color_id | Color
2 | 1 | null | Red
3 | 1 | null | Blue
4 | 1 | null | Other
```

Now I need the ability to store different data on select certain item. This may be one or more inputs. For example:

```
Color:
(o) Red
(o) Blue
(o) Other (please specify) ______________
```

How to store it? Create additional table or may be store with parent_id pointed to selected element or something else?

```
id | parent_id | code | name
4 | 1 | null | Other
5 | 4 | other_one | First text value
6 | 4 | other_two | Second text value
```

Comment: You are re-inventing XML... :-)   The more flexible you are, the more pain in the neck...  If you stick to this structure you'll get into hell soon... EAV is a very dangerous approach anyway. Hierarchical EAV is something I wouldn't even touch...

Comment: Since the "Other" option of your example effectively says "enter something custom, not related to the stuff we have in the database" - that implies an exception to the rule of pulling from the db. In that exceptional use case, I would (personally, so it's not a fact but opinion) use an additional table to store these user-input values.

Answer (score 0):

Thought a little bit about it... Here's a try to give you an answer to the question "How to store it":

Make sure, that you get partial structure into your concept. Define kind of types, value packages, things which belong together and use XML. Something like the above could loke like:

```
<settings>
   <parent id="1">
      <colors>
         <color>Red</color> --here you should think of tags to set the meaning of the color...
         <color>Red</color>
         <color>Other</color> --here you set whatever color you want
      </colors>
   </parent>
   <parent id="2">
   -- Your example with the "First text value" gives me this idea:
      <colors>
         <color meaning="BackColor">Red</color>
         <color meaning="BorderColor">Red</color>
         <color meaning="First text value">Blue</color> 
         <color meaning="Second text value">Green</color> 
      </colors>
   </parent>
</settings>
```

So my suggestion:

Try to define certain types like "FormColor" and let it be like

```
<FormColor backcolor="Red" forecolor="blue" first_text="green">
   --You may add specialities within the FormColor-element
   <SpecialColor meaning="SomeSpecialMeaning">Blue</SpecialColor>
</FormColor>
```

Place these "types" within a parent element. You can easily pick the parent element via `id` and read its inner XML. There you find everything you need...

With this approach you are as flexible as with your EAV thing, but much better readable, maintainable and better to evaluate.

Comment: How is XML related to a **relational database** exactly?

Comment: I'm not working with MySQL (rather SQL Server) but it must be roughly the same: You define a column in one of your tables, either of a string type or - if exists - a dedicated XML type. XML is nothing else than plain text... You can do the manipulation within your database or within your application or mix both...

Comment: @Mjh, what do you mean with "It's not working like that"?

Comment: MySQL doesn't work like SQL server. There's no such thing in MySQL. The OP is looking for a database-related solution, and posting an XML one doesn't help at all - how to use that solution with MySQL which doesn't support XML for data types?

Comment: I know that there is kind of support (look at `ExtractValue` and `UpdateXML`. Second one can load the XML as text into the application and manipulate it there. And allow me one question: How would you deal with a hierarchically nested EAV concept? You need recursive approaches. Don't think that MySQL can deal with this out of the box. but `XPath`and `XQuery` are designed to do this and they do this very well...

Comment: @Shnugo thank you for your answer, but I think it's more for output, than for store in relational database.

Comment: Not that you are not correct in your observations, but the issue is that MySQL doesn't work with XML. If you use approach of having an application written in language of your choice - that changes everything, however the question we're dealing here with is asking specifically how to store the information. Sadly, the answer you provided doesn't tackle that very issue :/

Comment: @SiZE, could be that I do not understand your needs... But you speak about "How to store it" and this is exactly the way I would store such data. Your hierarchically nested EAV is a concept which will lead you into hell very fast. But - of course - it's up to you...

Comment: @Mjh, but why? This is exactly the way I would store such data! What advantage is there with the EAV concept? If you allow any grade of flexibility you will end with potentially endless deep nestings, recursive queries and a big head ache... XML is - if you look at the concept - exactly the same as hierarchcal-EAV, but there are perfect tools to deal with that. And there are much better ways to define groups, to explain data with attributes and so on...

Comment: @SiZE, this might be interesting: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1101412-373-1.aspx

Comment: I'm not trying to argue your approach. If the OP has EAV in place and it works and if the issue is about storing additional data - how is changing the underlying structure and the whole system he's got in place the answer to his problem? You are suggesting fundamental change in the architecture. Bear in mind I'm not questioning your choice at all, which is why I'm not getting into whole why EAV, why XML, EAV vs XML etc.

Comment: @Mjh, OK, that's a fair point. I got the question in the way, that the concept is still in development. But you are right, that one can take it as "is working for years and I want to enhance it". In this case one might think to allow XML portions within the existing columns. Better grouping, better type safety, better strucuter...